# How to embed a URL in a string while posting on Facebook using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share a URL on Facebook and Twitter using `UIActivityViewController`. The problem is the URL is very long. Can I give a hyperlink or shorten it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share URL itself the following way

```
NSURL *longURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ longURL ] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```